# Using Hadoop, are my reducers guaranteed to get all the records with the same key?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, uniq

I'm running a Hadoop job using Hive actually that is supposed to `uniq` lines in many text files. In the reduce step, it chooses the most recently timestamped record for each key.

**Does Hadoop guarantee that every record with the same key, output by the map step, will go to a single reducer, even if many reducers are running across a cluster?**

I worry that the mapper output might be split after the shuffle happens in the middle of a set of records with the same key.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All values for a key are sent to the same reducer.  See this [Yahoo! tutorial](http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module4.html) for more discussion.

This behavior is determined by the partitioner, and might not be true if you use a partitioner other than the default.

Comment: actually i am not sure of this. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26693034/hadoop-strange-behaviour-reduce-function-doesnt-get-all-values-for-a-key  . I didn't modify the partitioner in my program.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, no!  You could create a `Partitioner` that sent the same key to a different reducer each time the `getPartition` is called.  It's just not generally a good idea for most applications.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Hadoop does guarantee that all keys that are the same will go to the same Reducer. This is achieved using a Partition function which buckets the keys using a hash function.

For more information on the Partitioning process take a look at this: [Partitioning Data](http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module5.html#partitioning)

It specifically talks about how different mappers that process the same key ensure that all keys of a given value end up in the same partition, and thus are processed by the same reducer.